# Where To Store App Files in Android So That Other Apps Can Access Them (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, file-access

There are a tonne of questions about where to store data on Android and I don't want to duplicate any of those. This article gives some starting points to answer this question:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Most other articles are telling me to put files here:
System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal

But, I need other apps to be able to access the file. Which folder should I choose so that I can navigate to the folder from a file explorer on Android, or be able to copy the file to my Windows machine via USB.

I tried the folder System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData at random, but the app errored and I wasn't able to write the file.

Essentially, all I am asking is: **which folder can I write to in an Android app that I can easily get to from outside the application**? I'm happy to add permissions. This is mainly for debugging purposes right now.

Answer (score 2):

Store your files in [External Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) by getting the external storage path with [`Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

Example:

```
public class FileStorage
{
    public string MyExternalFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "MyAppFolder");
        }
    }

    public void SaveToExternalStorage(string fileName, string content)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(MyExternalFolder, fileName);

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, content);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks about right. But, System.Environment doesn't contain a ExternalStorageDirectory property. Which namespace does the Environment class belong to?

Comment: Visual studio still won't accept that. It's saying I must be missing an assembly reference...

Comment: Is this in a Xamarin.Android app? Check if Mono.Android is referenced.

Comment: It's not referencing that. How do I add that reference?

Comment: It should be a default project reference for a new Android app. I don't use Visual Studio Windows so unfortunately can't help fully. Try right clicking on references and finding "Mono.Android".

Comment: Nah, it's not there. And, it's not in NuGet either.

Comment: What is the project type you are trying to call the above code from?

Comment: It's a csproj. <Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">. This is Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Specifically, is this inside a PCL or an Android library project?

Comment: Android. But, this is my bad. I think I was doing something wrong when trying to add the reference and it seems fine now. My namespace was "Adapt.Presentation.Android", which was causing a conflict so I added this using: "using os = Android.OS;"

Comment: Great to hear. If this solved the issue, accepting the answer will let future readers know its a solution :)

Comment: I hope so. My computer just got fried so I can't test it.

Comment: OK. So after  almost 3 days of downtime reinstalling Windows 10, I was finally able to test this. The error I get is: "Could not open database file: /storage/emulated/0/Xivic/Xivic.db (CannotOpen)". I tried adding the permissions: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but no luck.

Comment: What is external storage exactly? Is it an SD card? If that's the case, I've been barking up the wrong tree here. I don't have an SD card in my phone.

Comment: The Environment class tells me that the external storage state is "mounted", whatever that means.